# Why does UIToolbar break when I use the top autosizing constraint?

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, uitoolbar, autosize

Currently running Xcode 5.1 Beta 4 (5B90F)

Trying to snap a toolbar to the bottom of a `.xib` view. I'm using the autosizing constraints to manage its displacement. The constraints work well and align the toolbar just to where I'd like it to be horizontally, but not vertically:

[image]

Notice the top constraint that isn't applied to the toolbar. Whenenever I apply this, I'm unable to use the toolbar buttons in the simulator. However, if I don't apply the constraint my toolbar rebelliously floats in the middle of my view:

[image]

Is this a bug in Xcode 5 or does it have something to do with my view hierarchy? The toolbar and a drawing view are the only elements within the `.xib` view. I tried `Editor > Pin` and `Editor > Resolve Autolayout Issues` but I'm unable to select the menus.

Comment: Did you make sure that the `UIToolBar` parent is growing correctly in the height and width?

Comment: What do you mean growing correctly?

Comment: The view that is containing the the toolbar, have you set it autoresize mask correctly to grow.